# Executing binary does not work and does not return anything, although expected

Tags: bash

I have downloaded biber from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.6/binaries/Linux/

Neither the 64bit nor the 32bit executables work for me:
After downloading and extracting the archive running:

```
./biber --help
```

does not output anything (it returns me to bash). I have also installed texlive 2013 pretesting and there the biber compiler does not work either (same symptoms: nothing happens at all). :(. 
Has anybody an idea what to do? I have tested various versions of biber offered to download on sourceforge but did not get any of them working.

I would be very happy if you could help me :)

I am running on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Have you checked if this is something that needs to be compiled first?

Comment: of course ... this is a precompiled binary packaged in an archive.

Comment: is anybody willing to test if the executable works for them?
It is really only one executable: Downloading, unpacking, executing.
I would be very glad if sb. could report back, whether the issue affects them too or not. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: output of strace biber: http://pastebin.com/X0tC5ABz

Comment: okay, problem solved: sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp did the trick, as /tmp was mounted with noexec option. biber is packed with par, which extracts to /tmp before executing. 
Could somebody with enough reputation score edit my question in order to make the solution more obvious? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem solved:

`sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp`

did the trick, as `/tmp` was mounted with `noexec` option.

Biber is packed with par, which extracts to `/tmp` before executing, so `/tmp` has to allow execution.

This could be verified by looking at the output of `strace biber`: http://pastebin.com/X0tC5ABz

where

`stat("/tmp/par-75736572/cache-371b0cf3aa3eec4dfb0c82647515336d327c4e62/libperl.so.5.10.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1503704, ...}) = 0
execve("/tmp/par-75736572/cache-371b0cf3aa3eec4dfb0c82647515336d327c4e62/biber", ["biber"], [/* 73 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
exit_group(255)`

gives the hint.

As I don't have enough reputation score: Could somebody change the title, to be more general, so that people facing a similar problem have the chance to find a solution:
Example: Executing binary returns to command prompt with no output, although expected.